# Struts2 use <s:select> with <s:iterator>

Tags: struts2, struts

Is it possible to define a Struts Select field, `<s:select>`, with an Iterator for options, `<s:iterator>`?

e.g., I don't want to use the Key/Value/List properties,

```
<s:select id="criteriaRequestStatusList" name="searchRequestCriteria.requestStatusList" 
list="requestStatuses" 
listValue="description" listKey="id" />
```

because I have some special symbols such as `&nbsp;` coming from the server side and they aren't escaped.

The following works regarding escaping `&nbsp;`, but it's an HTML Select. I don't want to use this either, because it doesn't populate the form values properly on load.

```
<select id="criteriaRequestStatusList" name="searchRequestCriteria.requestStatusList" class="requestor input-block-level" name="requestors" multiple="multiple">
    <s:iterator value="requestStatuses">
        <option value="${id}">${description}</option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

My goal is,

```
<s:select ..>
   <s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value on the POHTML select using the normal `value` attribute.

The `<s:select>` tag expects values to be ready-to-use; personally I'd transform them on the server side before exposing them to the view layer.

You *might* be able to use OGNL in the `listTitle` property (I might have the property name wrong) to un-entity it; I don't recall.